# Logstash Produces No Output

Tags: csv, logstash, elastic-stack

I followed [the tutorial found here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set up the ELK stack, and eventually I managed to get everything working. When I tried to modify the system to read in CSV files, however, it stopped working entirely. The conf file looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/user/remaining/path/*.csv"
    type => "transaction"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "transaction" {
      csv {
            columns => ["@timestamp", "ip address", "domain", "user", "demo", "id", "activity", "detail"]
            separator => ","
          }
    }

}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    action => "index"    
    index => "logstash-test"
    workers => 1
  }
}
```

I've tried following a number of tutorials and guides for setting this up, and as far as I can tell logstash is still connected to elasticsearch. I just don't see any output. My suspicion is that it isn't reading the files at all. Part of the problem is that I'm not sure how to test each component of logstash. Is there something I'm likely to have missed?

Edit:
csv files look generally like this:

```
2016-02-29T22:26:39.319700,22.111.11.11,place.domain.ca,bob,DEMO,95081299250aa8,TI_START,"{'field': 'data', 'field2': 'moredata', 'anotherfield': 'evenmoredata', 'continuedfield': 'habbo', 'size': '16'}"
2016-02-29T22:27:00.098426,24.111.11.11,otherplace.domain.ca,bob,DEMO,390s8clearlyfake,TI_END,"{'field': 'data', 'field2': 'moredata', 'anotherfield': 'evenmoredata', 'continuedfield': 'habbo', 'size': '16'}"
```

I've also noticed that when I go to localhost:9200/logstash-test/ I'm getting a 404. I'm not sure if this is because there's no data transmitting, or if it's a different connection issue.

Comment: If there is a file like ~/.sincedb_.... remove it and try again.

Comment: Good idea, I tried it but no luck. Can I get any useful information from the new one that was created?

Comment: If you provide a few lines from csv files I could try to debug issue if it is because of conf file.

Comment: Thanks, there's a json file at the end of it which probably doesn't help, but as I understand the system it should simply append column8, column9, etc. Setting it to be entirely automated doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: It seems to work when deleting sincedb file. If there was connection issue stdout will print anyway and you will get errors about connection. There can be another logstash process running?

Comment: I used rm ~/.sincedb* to ensure they were all gone. When I run logstash with the -v flag, it seems as though logstash is making no attempt to process any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the discussion here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-not-showing-any-output-solved/28636/16

My files were more than 24 hours old, which is the default expiry time for a file input. It was fixed by changing the following where ignore_older was 86400 as a default:

```
input {
  file {
    ignore_older => 864000
    path => "/home/sean/cost-logs/transaction/*.csv"
    type => "transaction"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```